# Beamer TOC of sections of all parts

Tags: beamer

The command `\tableofcontents` works only for either the current part or a part that can be specified by a number (e.g., setting `\tableofcontents[part=2]`). However, I can't see how to get a "global" TOC that shows all sections of all parts of a beamer presentation. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please always include a short, but compilable test document in your questions.